# Understand async/await proposal in ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

As async said, pormise object or simple data(such as number or string) can follow by await, when it's simple data, it just as sync, I write the following first program:

```
let fs = require('fs');

async function readF(){
   let data1 = await fs.readFileSync('./file1.txt','utf-8');
   console.log(data1);
   let data2 = fs.readFileSync('./file2.txt','utf-8');
   console.log(data2);
}
readF();
console.log('outter hello');
```

and the result is :

```
outter hello
first file
second file
```

It seems that the readF function is async? why?

and I write a second program, just change the await to the second file reader:

```
let fs = require('fs');

async function readF(){
   let data1 = fs.readFileSync('./file1.txt','utf-8');
   console.log(data1);
   let data2 = await fs.readFileSync('./file2.txt','utf-8');
   console.log(data2);
}
readF();
console.log('outter hello');
```

this time, the result is:

```
first file
outter hello
second file
```

I can't understand this strange amazing result, I hope you can help me.

Comment: async/await is not part of ES2016

Comment: *"It seems that the readF function is async? why?"* Because you defined it as `async function readF() {}`? `let data1 = await x; console.log(data1);` is basically syntactic sugar for `Promise.resolve(x).then(data1 => console.log(data1); )`. `.then` callbacks are always resolved asynchronously.

Comment: async is part of ES7(ES2016)

Comment: Are you familiar with asynchronous code? Try doing `setTimeout(readF, 0)` and it will have the same result as your first example without the `async` keyword.

Comment: And it's not part of ES2016 either ;-P

Comment: *"async is part of ES7(ES2016)"* No. It's a [**proposal**](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md). It will be part of ES2017 (to be released in 2017, i.e. next year). There is no mention of `async` functions in the [ES2016 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/).

Comment: Note that you can use Async/Await now with Babel, see [babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/)

Comment: Maybe you also have a misunderstanding of what `async/await` does. It does *not* make your code magically synchronous (that's not possible). It lets you *write* asynchronous code in a *synchronous fashion* (i.e. without callbacks). But the code is still asynchronous and uses callbacks under the hood. It's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: why did I see the async/await is part of es7?

Comment: Maybe because that's a not uncommon mistake (unfortunately). When ES2016 wasn't finalized yet people thought that proposal might still make it into ES2016. However, since January 2016 (this year) it was clear that it wouldn't.

Comment: OK, I see, maybe you are right, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded, which means it can only execute one thing at any one time. Asynchronous code executes when all synchronous code is completed.

The syntax of `async` and `await` is that an operation marked as `await` can only occur inside a function marked `async`, and it marks the point in the code at which to continue executing when the synchronous code is complete.

In JavaScript versions that don't have these features yet, you can emulate it using `setTimeout` with a delay of `0`. `setTimeout` executes the callback function asynchronously. If you put all statements after `await` inside a `setTimeout` block, you can see that the behavior is the same:

```js
function async(){
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("first file");
       console.log("second file");
   }, 0);
}

async();
console.log('outer hello');
```

```js
function async(){
   console.log("first file");
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("second file");
   }, 0);
}

async();
console.log('outer hello');
```

Comment: I see, Thanks a lot